# Populating a control from an enumeration

Tags: enums, vb6, controls

Say I have the following enumeration:

```
Public Enum TimeUnit
  Day
  Week
  Month
  Year
End Enum
```

Is there any way I can use this enumeration to populate a ComboBox or ListBox?  Ideally, I'd like the control to echo the internal representation as the inserted value (i.e. `Day`, not `0`).

---

If there is a better way to go about this (c.f. 'X/Y Problem'), my basic requirement is that I must be able to use `TimeUnit` *similarly to* an enumeration, i.e. as a type in itself. I would also *really* like to avoid repeating myself in the code.

Comment: Note that I *do* mean VB6, not VB.NET. :-)

Comment: You don't want to do this.  If you try to use "friendly" UI naming for members of enumerations you run into reserved word collisions or overload semi-reserved words and in general have a mess on your hands.  `Day` and the rest shown above already have a meaning and so would normally be named something like `tuDay` anyway, specifically to avoid namespace collisions.

Comment: @Bob77 Fair enough. If you present an alternate approach, I'll modify the question appropriately to just ask a question on the base problem. I don't really see a good way of doing this. (At least, not with the knowledge I have of the language: I'm still in training.)

Comment: I don't think that the "names" you give to enums in pretty much any language are available to the program at runtime. They're a way of making code more readable - the actual program just sees 1,2,3 etc

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to use the enum to pass as a value to some method. You can assign the enum value to the **ItemData** property, and literal values to the Item (text the user sees). I would suggest using Bob77's naming convention and writing a method to populate your combobox or listbox control. Something like below should work.

```
Private Sub LoadCombo()

    Combo1.Clear
    Combo1.AddItem "Day"
    Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.NewIndex) = TimeUnit.Day
    Combo1.AddItem "Week"
    Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.NewIndex) = TimeUnit.Week
    Combo1.AddItem "Month"
    Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.NewIndex) = TimeUnit.Month
    Combo1.AddItem "Year"
    Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.NewIndex) = TimeUnit.Year

End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_Click()

    MsgBox "You have selected " & Combo1.Text & " (" & CStr(Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.ListIndex)) & ")"

End Sub
```

Comment: No idea why those "floating parens" are in there (the IDE inserts a space to try to tell you not to use them on a method call).  But I'm not sure there is any better answer than this, especially if the Enum values could be discontinuous or begin at a value other than 0.

Comment: @Bob77 You're correct about the parens. Too many years of C#. They do work though I'll remove them from the answer to be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping you'd refrain from sticking a `Call` keyword in front of each one. ;)